# C++ (SFML) gives a strange error about the file

Tags: c++, dll, sfml

For about 3 hours I sat with the gpt chat and tried to solve the problem with the SFML library. After I was finally able to compile the file, when I run it I get a very strange error about the dll file. And the problem is not even that the program does not find it, this one, like all other dll files, are in the source file and in the sysWOW64 folder, the gpt chat even gave up and advised to turn to the forums because he does not know the cause of the error. I will be very grateful if anyone can help me solve this.

Error: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ygFmWSC1EPNicD7a7

File main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Test"); // Создаем окно размером 800x600 пикселей

    sf::CircleShape circle(50); // Создаем круг радиусом 50 пикселей
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red); // Задаем кругу красный цвет
    circle.setPosition(375, 275); // Устанавливаем позицию круга в окне

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close(); // Закрываем окно при нажатии на кнопку "Закрыть"
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black); // Очищаем окно черным цветом
        window.draw(circle); // Рисуем круг в окне
        window.display(); // Отображаем содержимое окна на экране
    }

    return 0;
}
```

file c_cpp _properties(I use vs code):

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/SFML/include"
      ],
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/**",
          "C:/SFML/include"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      },
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        "-IC:/SFML/include",
        "-LC:/SFML/lib",
        "-lsfml-graphics",
        "-lsfml-window",
        "-lsfml-system"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I tried to solve the problem (more precisely, a lot of problems) with the GPT chat, I managed to get rid of most of it, and it seems to me that this is the last mistake on my way, as a result, the program window should be created and a circle should be drawn (or should not matter, the main thing so that the window starts without errors)

Comment: Can you translate the error to English and add it as text to your question?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, that's what it's called "procedure entry point _ZNSt15basic_streambuflcSt11char_traitslcEE7seekposESt4fposliESt13_los_Openmode not found in library
C:\0_CppTest\sfml-system-2.dll"

Comment: It can't find the runtime library dll files. They are probably in the gcc bin directory. You need to add that to your path or copy them to the directory you are running the program from.

Comment: I have added all the dll files, both in the library folder and in the project folder and in the computer's system folder

Comment: You've missed something. https://www.dependencywalker.com/ may help. Putting files into sysWOW64 is generally a very bad idea btw. It's also possible your version of SFML was compiled against a different library version.

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh thank you, now I will try something and write